# Websphere used implementation for DistributedMap

Tags: java, serialization, websphere

I want to serialize the `DistributedMap` object that is read from Websphere cache objects.

So, I need to extend it's implementation to implement `Serializable` interface. But I cannot find on Websphere [JavaDoc](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/cache/DistributedMap.html) any related implementation, only other abstract class. And using it gives a cast exception from Websphere, saying cannot cast from `DistributedMapImpl` to my custom class.

To make my question clear, I want to implement a custom tool to manually replicate cache objects from a WAS instance to another WAS instance.

If there is another suggestions. would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Extending WebSphere's `DistributedMap` implementation - even if it was possible - wouldn't help you much. When instantiating the cache, WebSphere would still instantiate its own `DistributedMap` implementation, not yours.

If what you need is to replicate cache objects, the correct way to do so (using WebSphere's dynamic cache) would be to define a "Replication Domain" and include your server instances within that domain. That way, WebSphere will automatically handle the replication of cache objects among domain members.

Another alternative would be to use an external distributed cache product, such as EHCache.

Comment: Well, thank you ..
But I want to do a manual cache replication, as I meet cases with server instances fail the automatic replication! so till the decision be taken to use EHCache, I needed to implement a manual tool for that

Comment: I'm guessing that what you see is the server failing to do an *instant* replication. It's a known thing. The cache replication will never be instant, neither with WAS nor with EHCache. Remember, that a "cache", by definition, needs not be instantly replicated. A "cache" is a collection of recreateable items. You may actually end up using a database after all.

Comment: Yea, I guess you are right .. I'll need to use database, thanks man.